# How to create an array in Rust in parallel and return it to C#?

Tags: c#, rust, interop

I try to create an array in parallel in Rust and return it to C# via DLL bindings. The first 4 elements are invalid.

Without `ThreadPool` and synchronization, I get the right results. The real calculation is more complex, but the following code is a simplified version without real calculation.
I have also tried `int*` instead of `IntPtr` but got the same invalid results.

Finally, I am new to Rust and do welcome any suggestions to improve the code.

Simplified Rust calculation

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create_array(len: libc::c_int, result:*mut *mut libc::c_int){
    let mut result_vec: Vec<libc::c_int> = vec![0;len as usize];
    let sync_result=Arc::new(Mutex::new(result_vec));
    let pool=ThreadPool::new(6);

    println!("From Thread");
    for i in 0..(len){
        pool.execute({
            let clone = Arc::clone(&sync_result);
            move||{
            let mut result_vec = clone.lock().unwrap();
            result_vec[i as usize]=i;
            if i<10{
                println!("{}:{}",i,result_vec[i as usize]);
            }
        }});
    } 
    pool.join();

    let  mut result_vec = Arc::try_unwrap(sync_result).unwrap().into_inner().unwrap();

    println!("Unwrapped Vector");
    for i in 0..10{
        println!("{}:{}",i,result_vec[i as usize]);
    }
    let result_data = result_vec.as_mut_ptr();
    unsafe{
        println!("Raw data");
        *result=result_data;
        for i in 0..10 as isize{
            println!("{}:{}",i,ptr::read(result_data.offset(i)));
        }
    }
    std::mem::forget(result_data);
}
```

C# Binding and function call

```
[DllImport(@"libs\OptimizationRust.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void create_array(int len, out IntPtr result);
public void RustCpuSerial()
{
    IntPtr resultPtr;
    int len = 10000;
    create_array(len,out resultPtr);

    int[] results = new int[len];
    Marshal.Copy(resultPtr, results, 0, results.Length);
}
```

Rust output:

```
From Thread
0:0
5:5
7:7
8:8
9:9
1:1
3:3
4:4
6:6
2:2

Unwrapped Vector
0:0
1:1
2:2
3:3
4:4
5:5
6:6
7:7
8:8
9:9

Raw data
0:0
1:1
2:2
3:3
4:4
5:5
6:6
7:7
8:8
9:9
```

C# Output:

```
0:-314008176
1:672
2:-314139296
3:672
4:4
5:5
6:6
7:7
8:8
9:9
```

Any ideas, what causes this behaviour?

Comment: Can you check whether the pointer addresses are actually the same going across the boundary?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld resultPtr is 0x000002404d35d480 in C# and `println!("Pointer address {:p}",result)`; prints "Pointer address 0x410437d650" - not the same, or do i have to obtain the values differently? But result_data has the same as in c#.

Comment: Yeah, it had nothing to do with that, I think. Writing up a solution.

Comment: It looks different from the question, but is this article helpful? [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/slice_arguments/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, apologies, the second half of the FFI barrier will be C. I have no suitable environment to showcase my C# skills.

Let's start by summarizing your code a bit, and drop all the threading (since it does nothing but confuse us when the issue isn't there)

The rust half is effectively this:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create_array(len: libc::c_int, result:*mut *mut libc::c_int){ // You're passing a pointer to a collection
    let mut result_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![];  // You create a Vec<>
    for i in 0..(len){
        result_vec.push(i); // You fill it...
    }
    let result_data = result_vec.as_mut_ptr(); // You then get a *mut ptr to it
    unsafe{
        *result=result_data; // You then assign the content of the pointer-to-a-pointer of what you received to the result ptr you just acquired
    }
    std::mem::forget(result_data); // And then you forget your data, because it is referenced elsewhere
}
```

This is before any changes. I've added comments to summarize what you ended up doing.

And sure enough, I can reproduce the bug with this code when FFIing from C:

[image]

Here is the "fixed" version:

```
pub extern "C" fn create_array(len: libc::c_int,result:*mut *mut libc::c_int){
    let mut results_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![];
    for i in 0..(len) {
      results_vec.push(i);
    }

    let mut result_slice = results_vec.into_boxed_slice(); // Change #1: Vec -> Box<[i32]>
    let result_data = result_slice.as_mut_ptr(); // We then get a *mut out of it
    unsafe {
        *result = result_data; // Same step as yours, we then overwrite the old pointer with its address
        // Do note that you may have leaked memory there if the pointer is not null.
        for i in 0..10 as isize{
            println!("{}:{}",i,ptr::read((*result).offset(i)));
        }
    }
    // We then forget *the boxed slice*. This is the important bit.
    std::mem::forget(result_slice);
}
```

This works, at least with a small amount of test code written in C. The reason it works and the original version doesn't is that you were not forgetting the right thing, primarily - you were forgetting the **pointer** to the `Vec`, not the `Vec` itself. As a result, the entire chunk of memory was technically uninitialized and evidently used for something else in between the FFI usage and your printing out of the data.

In practice, instead of calling `result_slice.as_mut_ptr()`, you'll be calling `Box::into_raw(result_slice)`, which has the advantage of not making you have to remember to `forget` the slice.

Comment: Perfect. glad to have helped! :-)

Comment: You should use `result_slice.into_raw()` instead of `as_mut_ptr`, which means you can't forget to `mem::forget` `result_slice`.

Comment: @trentcl I wanted to highlight the issue and deliberately kept the `mem::forget` call as a result, as that's where the issue was. I will add a small disclaimer, though